# Solve the initial value problem of $u_t-uu_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

$u_t-uu_x=0$  the initial value is $u(1,x)=\begin{cases}-1&x<0\\3&x>0\end{cases}$

This is what i have done so far

$$\frac {dx}{dt} = -u$$
using ordinary differential method like separate the variable i will have $$dx =-udt$$ then integrate both sides to get $$ x=-ut +c$$ so the general solution to this PDE is $$u(t,x)=x+ut$$
then i plug in my initial value to get $$u(1,x)=x+u$$. So far i feel confident about the computation, but i do not get the initial value part well meaning do i have to do something more or is it just like that. What does the -1 and 3 do that is the part i do not get. any help or explanation about how to use the initial value will be great thanks

Comment: I think you can use Fourier transform to make an ansatz, then you can get a linear equations system and ode's about the Fourier coefficients. You might solve this and plug the coefficients into the formel. But this is just an naive idea from the Heat equation, i'm not sure this is right, but you can try.

Comment: u is a function of t. your solution does not satisfy the equation. dx=u dt is solved by integrating u wrt t. $$u=\frac{kx+c_2}{-kt+c_1}$$ I have no idea how I would impose the boundary conditions.

Comment: @yongyong i can't use fourier

Comment: @user146269 Why? I mean just some sort of intuitive try to find an ansatz for solving problems but not as strictly solving method. Maybe you will find an appropriate formel and adding some conditions to make it applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\begin{cases}p=t-1\\q=x\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_t=u_pp_t+u_qq_t=u_p$

$u_x=u_pp_x+u_qq_x=u_q$

$\therefore u_p-uu_q=0$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dp}{ds}=1$ , letting $p(0)=0$ , we have $p=s$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=0$ , letting $u(0)=u_0$ , we have $u=u_0$

$\dfrac{dq}{ds}=-u=-u_0$ , letting $q(0)=f(u_0)$ , we have $q=f(u_0)-u_0s=f(u)-up$ , i.e. $u=F(q+up)=F(x+u(t-1))$

$u(1,x)=\begin{cases}-1&x<0\\3&x>0\end{cases}$ :

$\therefore u(t,x)=\begin{cases}-1&x+u(t-1)<0\\3&x+u(t-1)>0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}-1&x-t+1<0\\3&x+3t-3>0\end{cases}$

Hence $u(t,x)=\begin{cases}-1&x-t<-1\\3&x+3t>3\\c&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: @user146269 Note that the method of characteristics can only be used until characteristics intersect (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 0):

This equation is very similar to the inviscid Burgers' equation. Here is a plot of the characteristics in the $x$-$t$ plane obtained from the proposed initial data (up to a vertical translation in time by $-1$):

[image: characteristics]

One can observe that the characteristic curves intersect. Therefore, a shock wave occurs. Its speed $s$ is given by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition with data $u_L = -1$ on the left and $u_R = 3$ on the right:
$$
s = \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(u_L)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(u_R)^2}{u_L - u_R} = -\frac{1}{2} (-1 + 3) = -1 \, .
$$
Therefore, the entropy solution is
$$
u(x,t) =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& {-1} & &\text{if}\quad x<{-(t-1)}\\
& 3 & &\text{if}\quad {-(t-1)}<x
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$